# STL containers with fixed growth

Tags: c++, stl

I have a use case for containers that provide fixed growth patterns instead of exponential ones. In this use case, conserving memory is more important than runtime.
Is there a way to make `std::vector` or `std::list` to grow with N elements automatically instead of growing exponentially whenever the container runs out of space?
I know I can write an adapter that does this but I first want to find out if it's possible through standardized means.

If it's not possible, is there a boost container I can use?

Comment: std::list allocates one node at a time.

Comment: What makes you think std::list grows exponentially?

Comment: The standard library does not provide that functionality. `std::vector`'s resizing scheme is firmly in the hands of the standard library implementer.

Comment: @François Andrieux That's not quite correct. Since back insertion time must be amortized constant, the implementation doesn't really have a choice but do exponential allocations.

Comment: @Frank But the constant they you c an be different.  MSVS uses 1.5 while gcc and clang use 2 for instance.

Comment: @NathanOliver but it's still exponential in both cases.

Comment: @Frank As far as I know all containers do this. If I'm wrong, please correct me.

Comment: @the_drow actually, only std::vector (and adapters defaulting to std::vector, like std::stack) have that behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::list` does not grow exponentially, it's a [doubly linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list) under the hood.

`std::vector` cannot grow by a constant number of elements, because of complexities of operations required by the standard. For example, the complexity of `push_back` should have `O(1)` amortized time complexity. With the constant size grow it would be `O(n)` complexity.

If you need a container that is quite similar to `std::vector` and has no exponential growth factor, take a look at `std::deque`.

Comment: Since I don't care about runtime here I'd rather have `O(n)` complexity. A list won't fit since I need to be able to allocate in bulks. Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: If you don't care about continuous storage, then it sounds like you want std::deque

Comment: I do care (somewhat). I'm trying to refactor https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/blob/next/src/containers/segmented_vector.hpp to some STL container if possible.

Comment: From a cursory glance, `segmented_vector_t` looks to be exactly what std::deque is.

Comment: @the_drow, You should take a look at `std::deque`, seems quite similar

Comment: If you explicitly call `resize` or `reserve` on the vector, you can explicitly control the growth scheme of the vector.